# Telegram timed response

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am currently working on a Telegram Bot using the python api. I am using this example here https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py. With that example I want the bot to have a timed response.

For example if the user does not respond within 30 sec send a "Are you still there message" or something and after 1 min end the conversation. The reason I want to implement something like this is because the conversation does not close if there is no response. It is in that state until the I end the script. Therefore the user can not send /start command to start all over. I was able to find this https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/ext/conversationhandler.py where it states I can enable allow_reentry. I did and it sort of solves that issue where the user can start a new converation over and over using the command /start. But I would still like to have the conversation end after a set amount of time. To end a conversation I need to return ConversationHandler.END

I have tried a while loop counting down from 9 with a time.sleep of 2 each time. with it reading the response update.message.text but it only reads the command /start which means I can never advance in the script, unless I return it using return GENDER but I am not able to find a method in which I can tell when the user has chosen the gender to then return GENDER.

So how do I implement an timer based response? Thank You

`from telegram import (ReplyKeyboardMarkup)
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, RegexHandler,
                          ConversationHandler)

import logging

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION, BIO = range(4)


def start(bot, update):
    reply_keyboard = [['Boy', 'Girl', 'Other']]

    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id,
                    text='Hi! My name is Professor Bot. I will hold a conversation with you. '
                         'Send /cancel to stop talking to me.\n\n'
                         'Are you a boy or a girl?',
                    reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True))

    return GENDER


def gender(bot, update):
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("Gender of %s: %s" % (user.first_name, update.message.text))
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id,
                    text='I see! Please send me a photo of yourself, '
                         'so I know what you look like, or send /skip if you don\'t want to.')

    return PHOTO


def photo(bot, update):
    user = update.message.from_user
    photo_file = bot.getFile(update.message.photo[-1].file_id)
    photo_file.download('user_photo.jpg')
    logger.info("Photo of %s: %s" % (user.first_name, 'user_photo.jpg'))
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, text='Gorgeous! Now, send me your location please, '
                                                 'or send /skip if you don\'t want to.')

    return LOCATION


def skip_photo(bot, update):
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s did not send a photo." % user.first_name)
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, text='I bet you look great! Now, send me your '
                                                 'location please, or send /skip.')

    return LOCATION


def location(bot, update):
    user = update.message.from_user
    user_location = update.message.location
    logger.info("Location of %s: %f / %f"
                % (user.first_name, user_location.latitude, user_location.longitude))
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, text='Maybe I can visit you sometime! '
                                                 'At last, tell me something about yourself.')

    return BIO


def skip_location(bot, update):
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s did not send a location." % user.first_name)
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, text='You seem a bit paranoid! '
                                                 'At last, tell me something about yourself.')

    return BIO


def bio(bot, update):
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("Bio of %s: %s" % (user.first_name, update.message.text))
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id,
                    text='Thank you! I hope we can talk again some day.')

    return ConversationHandler.END


def cancel(bot, update):
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s canceled the conversation." % user.first_name)
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id,
                    text='Bye! I hope we can talk again some day.')

    return ConversationHandler.END


def error(bot, update, error):
    logger.warn('Update "%s" caused error "%s"' % (update, error))


def main():
    # Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Add conversation handler with the states GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION and BIO
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],

        states={
            GENDER: [RegexHandler('^(Boy|Girl|Other)$', gender)],

            PHOTO: [MessageHandler([Filters.photo], photo),
                    CommandHandler('skip', skip_photo)],

            LOCATION: [MessageHandler([Filters.location], location),
                       CommandHandler('skip', skip_location)],

            BIO: [MessageHandler([Filters.text], bio)]
        },

        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],

       allow_reentry=True

    )

    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until the you presses Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `JobQueue` for that.

You can see an example here: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/timerbot.py

Make sure to initialize your handler with `pass_job_queue=True` (as shown in the above example).